# Error:(22, 8) error: CustomAdaptor is not abstract and does not override abstract method getView(int,View,ViewGroup) in Adapter

Tags: android

```
public class CustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Rowitem> rowItems;

    CustomAdaptor(Context context, List<Rowitem> rowitems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = rowItems;
}


    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profile_pic;
        TextView Employees;
        TextView status;

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = null;


            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();


                holder.Employees = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp);
                holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
                holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

                Rowitem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

                holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
                holder.Employees.setText(row_pos.getEmployees());
                holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
}
}
}
}
```

Hello friends, this is my custom adapter and i am getting this error :-CustomAdaptor is not abstract and does not override abstract method getView(int,View,ViewGroup) in Adapter.......Could you plz help me out in this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put getView() method out side of holderclass and also write a return convertview statement.

```
public class CustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<Rowitem> rowItems;

CustomAdaptor(Context context, List<Rowitem> rowitems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = rowItems;
}


public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}


private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView profile_pic;
    TextView Employees;
    TextView status;
}
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;


        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();


            holder.Employees = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp);
            holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

            Rowitem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);

            holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
            holder.Employees.setText(row_pos.getEmployees());
            holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
        }
        return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: @Gur heppay to help you, if annswer helped you then don't forgot to accept it as right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `getView()` method outside Holder Class

```
public class CustomAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Rowitem> rowItems;

    CustomAdaptor(Context context, List<Rowitem> rowitems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = rowItems;
    }


    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }


    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView profile_pic;
        TextView Employees;
        TextView status;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
             holder = new ViewHolder();

             holder.Employees = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp);
             holder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
             holder.status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);

             convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        }

        Rowitem row_pos = rowItems.get(position);
        holder.profile_pic.setImageResource(row_pos.getProfile_pic_id());
        holder.Employees.setText(row_pos.getEmployees());
        holder.status.setText(row_pos.getStatus());
    }
}
```